# Testing functions returning option<T>

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fsunit

Consider unit-testing a module defining [strings of constrained length](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/) as a type for representing user names:

```
module UserName

type T = UserName of string
let create (userName : string) =
    if userName.Length >= 6 && userName.Length <= 16 
    then Some (UserName userName)
    else None
let apply f (UserName userName) = f userName
let value userName = apply id userName
```

A unit test to ensure that the function returns `None` for an invalid input looks simple:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``UserName must have at least six characters`` () =
    UserName.create "aaa" |> should equal None
```

However, a unit test for the case when the function returns `Some` appears to require an extra line for completeness of the `match` expression:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Valid UserName`` () =
    match UserName.create "validname" with
    | Some result ->
        UserName.value result |> should equal "validname"
    | None -> Assert.True(false)
```

This does not look right to me, because my tests must define code for testing the "unhappy" path that must yield a failure anyway.

I wish I could write this instead

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Valid UserName`` () =
    UserName.create "validname" |> should equal (Some (UserName "validname"))
```

but it does not compile (The value or constructor 'UserName' is not defined).

Is there a way to write a unit test of a function returning `option<T>` that does not require an explicit check of the "unhappy" path (e.g. `| None -> Assert.True(false)`)? I am open to adding more types and/or functions to the `UserName` module to make it more testable.

Comment: I guess you forgot to make the ctor private in the first snippet `type T = UserName of string`? Unless you made the constructor private, what you're trying to do should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `value` to the inside of `Some` and then compare:

```
UserName.create "validname" 
  |> Option.map UserName.value
  |> should equal (Some "validname")
```